# Container in a Stack Widget is taking whole height

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a container that takes up all height when placed in a stack widget. But, if I place it in a column (or anything else) it will only take enough height. I haven't set any value for height in the container.

When placed in a stack:

[image]

Then same container when placed in a column:

[image]

Comment: Try placing the container in column in a stack with alignment=bottom center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `Column`'s `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max`, you need to set `MainAxisSize.min`

```dart
child: Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [ ],
),
```